# How to Embed Youtube Videos using Object tag in Android?

Tags: android, video, webview, embed, youtube-api

I am trying to embed a youtube video on a xml file for my application.

Following is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tour_webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
  <object 
    width="480" 
    height="330">
    <param 
        name="movie" 
        value="http://www.youtube.com/v/tjxpMhGwXH4?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0">   
    </param>
    <param 
    name="allowFullScreen" 
    value="true">
</param>
<param 
    name="allowscriptaccess" 
    value="always">
</param>
<embed 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/v/tjxpMhGwXH4?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    width="480" 
    height="330" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" 
    allowfullscreen="true" />
</object>  
</WebView>
```

Following is my java file:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tours_04);
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.tour_webview);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjxpMhGwXH4");
    setContentView(wv);
}
```

Logcat says:

**Caused by abdroid.View.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7:Error inflating class object**

Help Needed!

Comment: there is no magic in exception ... Inflater doesn't know class 'object'

Comment: thanks..but again how do i embed the video..tried a lot..new to android can you help?

Comment: read documentation ... there is an sample how to load html from string to webview

Comment: sir, i read that as well to reconfirm, i was successful in displaying other url in different java files of my project but was not successful in embedding an object. can you please help.or please vote up for this so that others can also comment! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the confusion here is that you are attempting to embed HTML tags in an Android layout file, which is not HTML.  It is XML that is specific to Android, and is used only for inflating the layout elements and other components, one of which is indeed a WebView, but in order to get this working you will have to load a proper HTML file, or URL into your WebView instance, but you will not be able to embed a Flash object in the way you are trying to do.  If you go [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) you can read the documentation about how to load an HTML file into a WebView, which you will have to do if you want to display an HTML page with a Flash object.
The other method you could use, if you have the ability to do so, is to port whatever Flash object you want into an [Adobe AIR](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/flash-platform-in-action/use-flash-builder-to-develop-adobe-air-apps-for-android/) application and run it as a local AIR app on the Android device.